# How to achieve dynamic css class in ui-grid that reflects page content changes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid, ui-grid

My goal is to achieve a dynamic CSS class in ui-grid cells with simplest example being to color gender column or display an icon based on cell's value. The CSS classes would be updated according to current data on the page so if eg. a button is clicked that updates the data bound to the grid the classes would be recalculated.

There is plenty of examples from authors and contributors on dynamic CSS classes eg. http://brianhann.com/6-ways-to-take-control-of-how-your-ui-grid-data-is-displayed however they only describe a way to conditonally apply a class during page load and what I need is a way to get the behaviour that would reapply the rules on page contents changes as described above the way basic angular ng-class works.

In ui-grid you can use cell templates or cell class mechanisms in column definition but neither seems to work here:

```
 cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
    if (grid.getCellValue(row ,col).toLowerCase() === 'male') {
      return 'blue';
    }
  }

cellTemplate: 
    '<div ng-class="{ blue: \'{{COL_FIELD.sex}}\' == \'male\', 
    green: \'{{COL_FIELD.sex}}\' == \'female\'}">
    {{ COL_FIELD.first }} {{ COL_FIELD.last }}</div>'
```

I created a plunkr with a full example of this problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/rob144gVQo6uy1AVuJlS

I also tried calling various refresh methods on grid object and angular's $scope.apply but to no effect.

Comment: Did you try using variable bindings (not sure it is possible at all)? The idea would be to set the class as a bound variable and update it programmatically. Other alternative is (only reasonable if you would have very few possible variables) is to define the class as a conditional construct or use an angular filter WITHIN the html.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by any of that, you'd have to fork my plunkr or paste some code here - addding angular bindings is exactly what cellTemplate is supposed to do. Adding manual bindings outside ui-grid would of course not be very feasible.

Comment: I was thinking about something like (cannot commit about the syntax though): `<div class="{{ClassToUse}}" ....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to use grid.appScope object in the cell template by attaching a function to it:

```
cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{ \'my-css-class\': grid.appScope.rowFormatter(row) }"> ... '
```

where rowFormatter should be a binary function that has to be attached to scope in the controller:

```
$scope.rowFormatter = function(row) {
    return row.entity.gender === 'male';
};
```

This is actually there hidden in documentation examples: 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically cellCss without using cellTemplate.

You first have to register your gridApi somewhere in Code

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function ( gridApi ) { 
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
```

then, where ever the data is changing add a data change notification call

```
$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
```

this will basically tell ui-grid that data is changed and re-calculate the CSS value. [see here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3449#issuecomment-102524212)

Comment: Can confirm this works as stated, this should be the accepted answer.